# using Oracle Advanced Queue through JMS: NPE thrown at AQjmsProducer.jdbcEnqueue

Tags: java, oracle, jms

I'd like to use Oracle Advanced queue via JMS.

I've create queue table and queue via plsql like this:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE(
queue_table            => 'QT3',
queue_payload_type     => 'RAW');
END;
/

BEGIN
DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE( 
queue_name          => 'Q3', 
queue_table         => 'QT3'); 
END;
/
```

Then I try to send a message like this:

```
    System.setProperty("oracle.jms.traceLevel", "6");

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = AQjmsFactory.getConnectionFactory("x.x.x.x", "xxx", 1521, "thin");
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("xxx", "xxx");
    connection.start();

    Session session = connection.createSession(true, 0);
    Queue queue = session.createQueue("Q3");
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("valami");
    message.setJMSType("text");
    producer.send(message);
    session.commit();
```

The above code finds the queue (If I replace Q3 to something else then it says queue not found, so I guess that basic connection setup is OK), but I got NPE exception at producer.send. I set aqapi trace and I got this output:

```
main [Fri Jun 20 14:22:51 CEST 2014] AQjmsProducer.send-1:  entry
main [Fri Jun 20 14:22:51 CEST 2014] AQjmsProducer.send-main:  entry
main [Fri Jun 20 14:22:51 CEST 2014] AQjmsProducer.send:  queue: RISKOPALL.Q3
main [Fri Jun 20 14:22:51 CEST 2014] AQjmsProducer.send:  dest_queue: RISKOPALL.Q3
main [Fri Jun 20 14:22:51 CEST 2014] AQjmsProducer.jdbcEnqueue:  entry
main [Fri Jun 20 14:22:51 CEST 2014] AQjmsProducer.checkMessageType:  adt type: null
main [Fri Jun 20 14:22:51 CEST 2014] AQjmsProducer.checkMessageType:  message_class: oracle.jms.AQjmsTextMessage
main [Fri Jun 20 14:22:51 CEST 2014] AQjmsProducer.jdbcEnqueue:  exit
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsProducer.checkMessageType(AQjmsProducer.java:2362)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsProducer.jdbcEnqueue(AQjmsProducer.java:823)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsProducer.send(AQjmsProducer.java:747)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsProducer.send(AQjmsProducer.java:517)
    at aqjms.AqJmsTest.main(AqJmsTest.java:55)
```

I decompiled aqapi.jar and found that the NPE is thrown because "adtType" parameter is null at AQjmsProducer.checkMessageType.

What is this ADT type and How shall I set it correctly?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the payload type of the queue solved the problem:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE(
queue_table            => 'QT3',
queue_payload_type     => 'SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE',
compatible => '8.1.0');
END;
/
```